# Python - consumir api com loop para paginação

Tags: python

Atualmente eu consumo dados de uma api paginada utilizando python. Coloquei um número de paginas x, o problema é quando existem mais paginas, ou quando tem menos paginas e fica fazendo loop sem necessidade.
Sempre que a api tem uma proxima pagina, a mesma retorna a seguinte informação:

```
"has_next":true
```

e quando não tem

```
"has_next":false.
```

Seria possível eu fazer um loop olhando se existe a informação true,avanço para nova pagina, se retornar false ele encerra o loop ?

```
subd = 6
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
if subd >= 2:
    for page in a:
        request = curl.curlEc(subd, page)
```

segue o trecho de retorno em Json

```
[
   {
      "resultados":{
         "has_next":true,
         "current_page":1,
         "pedidos":[
            {
               "id":8809,
               "user":{
                  "id":2361,
                  "name":"",
                  "cpf":"",
                  "cnpj":"",
                  "sexo":"feminino",
                  "data_nascimento":" ",
                  "devices":[
                     
                  ]
               },
               "loja":"",
               "tipo_frete":null,
               "endereco_entrega":null,
               "forma_pagamento_entrega":"Débito",
               "cupom_desconto":null,
```

Comment: parece um problema a ser resolvido com o try statement. Veja documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando requests seria algo como:

```
import requests

page = 1

while True:
    # supondo que a chamada passe a página como parâmetro
    r = requests.get(f'https://dominio?page={page}')

    # testando resposta, se for diferente de 200 (OK), sai do loop
    if r.status_code != 200:
        break

    #assumindo que é uma lista com um único item
    results = r.json()[0]

    #
    # AQUI VC PROCESSA O RESULTADO
    #

    # apenas para ficar claro
    has_next = results["resultados"]["has_next"]
    
    page = page + 1

    if not has_next:
        break
```